# Web-Scraping with R

Tags: r, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm having some problems scraping data from a website. First, I have not a lot of experience with webscraping...
My intended plan is to scrape some data using R from the following website:
http://spiderbook.com/company/17495/details?rel=300795

Especially, I want to extract the links to the articles on this site.

My idea so far:

```
xmltext <- htmlParse("http://spiderbook.com/company/17495/details?rel=300795")
sources <- xpathApply(xmltext,  "//body//div")
sourcesCharSep <- lapply(sourcesChar,function(x) unlist(strsplit(x, " "))) 
sourcesInd <- lapply(sourcesCharSep,function(x) grep('"(http://[^"]*)"',x))
```

But this doesn't bring up the intended information. Some help would be really appreciated here! Thanks!

Best
Christoph

Comment: Well, for starters, you need to put the url in quotes in the first line...

Comment: Yes, that's right. I just pasted it in there as it is part of a larger script where it is looping over multiple pages & URLs.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You picked a tough problem to learn on.

This site uses javascript to load the article information. In other words, the link loads a set of scripts which run when the page loads to grab the information (from a database, probably) and insert it into the DOM. `htmlParse(...)` just grabs the base html and parses that. So the links you want are simply not present.

AFAIK the only way around this is to use the `RSelenium` package. This package essentially allows you to pass the base html through what looks like a browser simulator, which does run the scripts. The problem with `Rselenium` is that you need not only to download the package, but also a "Selenium Server". [This link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-basics.html) has a nice introduction to `RSelenium`.

Once you've done that, inspection of the source in a browser shows that the article links are all in the `href` attribute of anchor tags which have `class=doclink`. This is straightforward to extract using xPath. *NEVER NEVER NEVER* use regex to parse XML.

```
library(XML)
library(RSelenium)
url <- "http://spiderbook.com/company/17495/details?rel=300795"
checkForServer()        # download Selenium Server, if not already presnet
startServer()           # start Selenium Server
remDr <- remoteDriver() # instantiates a new driver
remDr$open()            # open connection
remDr$navigate(url)     # grab and process the page (including scripts)
doc   <- htmlParse(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
links <- as.character(doc['//a[@class="doclink"]/@href'])
links
# [1] "http://www.automotiveworld.com/news-releases/volkswagen-selects-bosch-chargepoint-e-golf-charging-solution-providers/"
# [2] "http://insideevs.com/category/vw/"                                                                                    
# [3] "http://www.greencarcongress.com/2014/07/20140711-vw.html"                                                             
# [4] "http://www.vdubnews.com/volkswagen-chooses-bosch-and-chargepoint-as-charging-solution-providers-for-its-e-golf-2"     
# [5] "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=84543228"                            
# [6] "http://insideevs.com/volkswagen-selects-chargepoint-bosch-e-golf-charging/"                                           
# [7] "http://www.calcharge.org/2014/07/"                                                                                    
# [8] "http://nl.anygator.com/search/volkswagen+winterbanden"                                                                
# [9] "http://nl.anygator.com/search/winterbanden+actie+volkswagen+caddy"
```

Comment: Can you use your browser's network inspector to get the ajax URL that is fetching the data? Then just GET that?

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As @jihoward notes `RSelenium` will solve this problem and wont require inspection of net traffic/ dissection of the underlying website to find the appropriate quantities. Also I would note that `RSelenium` can run without `Selenium Server` if `phantomjs` is installed on the users system. In this case `RSelenium` can drive `phantomjs` directly. There is a vignette relating to headless browsing at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSelenium/vignettes/RSelenium-headless.html

### Inspecting web traffic with browser

In this case however inspection of the traffic yields the following json file being called http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795&docs_page=0 and it is not cookie protected or sensitive to user-agent string etc.. In this instance the following can be done:

```
library(RJSONIO)
res <- fromJSON("http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795&docs_page=0")
> sapply(res$data, "[[", "url")
[1] "http://www.automotiveworld.com/news-releases/volkswagen-selects-bosch-chargepoint-e-golf-charging-solution-providers/"
[2] "http://insideevs.com/category/vw/"                                                                                    
[3] "http://www.greencarcongress.com/2014/07/20140711-vw.html"                                                             
[4] "http://www.vdubnews.com/volkswagen-chooses-bosch-and-chargepoint-as-charging-solution-providers-for-its-e-golf-2"     
[5] "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=84543228"                            
[6] "http://insideevs.com/volkswagen-selects-chargepoint-bosch-e-golf-charging/"                                           
[7] "http://www.calcharge.org/2014/07/"                                                                                    
[8] "http://nl.anygator.com/search/volkswagen+winterbanden"                                                                
[9] "http://nl.anygator.com/search/winterbanden+actie+volkswagen+caddy"
```

### Inspecting web traffic writing a simple function for phantomJS

With `RSelenium` and `phantomJS` we could also use it to inspect the traffic on the fly (currently only when driving phantomJS directly). As a simple example we record the requested and received calls from the current webpage we are viewing and store in "traffic.txt" in our current working directory:

```
library(RSelenium)
pJS <- phantom()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantom")
remDr$open()
appUrl <- "http://spiderbook.com/company/17495/details?rel=300795"
psScript <- "var page = this;
             var fs = require(\"fs\");
             fs.write(\"traffic.txt\", 'WEBSITE CALLS\\n', 'w');
             page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
                fs.write(\"traffic.txt\", 'Request: ' + request.url + '\\n', 'a');
             };
             page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
                fs.write(\"traffic.txt\", 'Receive: ' + response.url + '\\n', 'a');
             };"

result <- remDr$phantomExecute(psScript)

remDr$navigate(appUrl)
urlTraffic <- readLines("traffic.txt")
> head(urlTraffic)
[1] "WEBSITE CALLS"                                                        
[2] "Request: http://spiderbook.com/company/17495/details?rel=300795"      
[3] "Receive: http://spiderbook.com/company/17495/details?rel=300795"      
[4] "Request: http://spiderbook.com/static/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"        
[5] "Request: http://spiderbook.com/static/js/lib/jquery.dropkick-1.0.2.js"
[6] "Request: http://spiderbook.com/static/js/jquery.textfill.js"          

> urlTraffic[grepl("Receive: http://spiderbook.com/company/details", urlTraffic)]
[1] "Receive: http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795&docs_page=0"
[2] "Receive: http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795&docs_page=0"

pJS$stop() # stop phantomJS
```

Here we can see one of the received files was `"Receive: http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795&docs_page=0"`.

### Using phantomJS/ghostdriver built-in HAR support to inspect traffic

In fact `phantomJS/ghostscript` creates its own `HAR` files so just by browsing to the page when we are driving `phantomJS` we already have access to all the request/response data:

```
library(RSelenium)
pJS <- phantom()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantom")
remDr$open()
appUrl <- "http://spiderbook.com/company/17495/details?rel=300795"
remDr$navigate(appUrl)
harLogs <- remDr$log("har")[[1]]
harLogs <- fromJSON(harLogs$message)
# HAR contain alot of detail will just illustrate here accessing the data
requestURLs <- sapply(lapply(harLogs$log$entries, "[[", "request"), "[[","url")
requestHeaders <- lapply(lapply(harLogs$log$entries, "[[", "request"), "[[", "headers")
XHRIndex <- which(grepl("XMLHttpRequest", sapply(requestHeaders, sapply, "[[", "value")))

> harLogs$log$entries[XHRIndex][[1]]$request$url
[1] "http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795&docs_page=0"
```

So the last example shows interogating the HAR file produced by `phantomJS` to find the `XMLHttpRequest` requests and then return the specific url which as we would hope corresponds to the json file we found at the beginning of the answer.

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996370/r-error-in-f-x1l-y1l-scheme-not-supported-in-url-na thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Any browser's network inspector will tell you where its getting the data from. In this case it seems to be JSON via http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795 - which means its a two liner with jsonlite:

```
> require(jsonlite)
> x=fromJSON("http://spiderbook.com/company/details/docs?rel=300795")
> x$data$url
[1] "http://www.automotiveworld.com/news-releases/volkswagen-selects-bosch-chargepoint-e-golf-charging-solution-providers/"
[2] "http://insideevs.com/category/vw/"                                                                                    
[3] "http://www.greencarcongress.com/2014/07/20140711-vw.html"                                                             
[4] "http://www.vdubnews.com/volkswagen-chooses-bosch-and-chargepoint-as-charging-solution-providers-for-its-e-golf-2"     
[5] "http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/private/snapshot.asp?privcapId=84543228"                            
[6] "http://insideevs.com/volkswagen-selects-chargepoint-bosch-e-golf-charging/"                                           
[7] "http://www.calcharge.org/2014/07/"                                                                                    
[8] "http://nl.anygator.com/search/volkswagen+winterbanden"                                                                
[9] "http://nl.anygator.com/search/winterbanden+actie+volkswagen+caddy"
```

I suspect this part of the JSON tells you if the returned data has more pages:

```
> x$has_next
[1] FALSE
```

and then I suspect there's a parameter to the URL that gets data from a certain page.

How do you get the JSON url from the public URL? I'm not totally sure since I don't know what the "17495" is doing there...

Answer (score 0):

```
    library(rvest)
    library(tidyverse)
    library(janitor)
    
    wiki_link2<-"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Economy_of_China"
    
    wiki_page2<-read_html(wiki_link2)
    
    gdp_table2= wiki_page2 %>%  
      html_nodes("table") %>% html_table()%>% .[4] %>% .[[1]]
    .[4] %>% html_table()%>%.[[1]]
    
    View(gdp_table2)
    gdp_table2<-gdp_table2 %>% clean_names(case="snake")
    names(gdp_table2)
    
    gdp_table2$inflation_rate_in_percent<-as.numeric(sub("%","",gdp_table2$inflation_rate_in_percent))
    finaltable$unemploymentInPercent<-as.numeric(sub("%","",finaltable$unemploymentInPercent))



#Changing data into long form
nifty_50_long <- melt(nifty_50, id.vars= "weightage")

#Long to wide
goldsilver_wide<-dcast(goldsilver_long, variable ~ year, value.var="value")
view(goldsilver_wide)
```